# ?Sending a String created inside a method to another class

Tags: android, variables, gestures

I have code which has one activity which passes information to  a second activity. 
I can use this information to pass to a third activity with additional information from the result of the second activity.

I want to use gestures as a method of going back to a previous activity, but if I go back from the third to the second activity I need the information initially passed from the first to the second activity to still be present.

i.e.

First Acticity

what is Y?

answer y = 5

Second activity

User said Y = 5

what is X?

Third Activity

User said Y = 5
X = 6

Go back to Second activity but maintain the input of

User said Y = 5.

To do this I have used a bundle to pass the information between activities, but I can only access the info in the bundle from within a method within the class started by the intent.

the gesture controls are within another class, so I cannot access the bundle information from within this class as the getIntent command produces a not defined error.

What I need to do is to be able to pass the information from the bundle from the first activity to the gesture class so that I can pass it back when I go back using the gestures.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that you need to be able to recover the previously input data when you go back?

There are a couple options:

1: Instead of bundling the data with the intent, you can store the data in the application object (which you can obtain via `getApplication()`). This will make that data accessible from anywhere in your app.

2: Use SharedPreferences (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)). You simply map the value you want to store with a string and it is likewise accessible anywhere in your app

3: Store the value in a static field in whatever class is persistent throughout the app's lifetime. This is the easiest to execute, but not the best style (i suggest using this as a last resort only)

Good Luck! Let me know if this was helpful.